# Espresso: How can I iterate over multiple EditTexts?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I want to assert that no `EditText`s in my view hierachy are focused.

This is easily done with multiple `withId()` matchers, but is it possible to do this with a for loop to match any `EditText`s?

Comment: Hi Zak, not sure if it's possible with pure Espresso but you can always use the instrumentation tools from ActivityIntrumentationTestCase2 :                View rootView = getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content) and then recursively find all EditTexts for your rootView and perform whatever checks needed for them.